# Is there an easy way of knowing which tournaments are free to watch in-game?

Tags: dota-2

I watched The International 3 having recently got to DOTA2 and loved it.

I'd like to watch free past (and future, when available) tournaments in-game. Is there anywhere I can get a list of free to watch tournaments that are still available to watch in-game, and any future ones coming up?

So far i've been going into each tournament and trying to click through to watch it until I get the No Access message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only The International  are free (as far as tournament go) (EDIT : as specified by decency, Dreamhack invitational and The Nexon Starer League too). But you can watch all games from tournament that are streamed. The easiest way to know the schedule is to go here http://www.joindota.com/en/start on the right section "Matches" you have all the oncoming match and by clicking on them you can access all the streamers for those matches (usually Joindota Red/Blue, BeyondTheSummit, Or the official tournament stream)

EDIT : your question included past tournament, for past tournament the easiest way is to go here http://www.dotacinema.com/vods. You can filter by date, casters, team, tournament etc. So lets say you want to watch all matches between iG and Alliance, you go in the tab "Teams" and select iG and Alliance (you can type the name for autosearch). You can also apply several filters (like iG vs Alliance but only streamed by Tobiwan, or at this specific date, or only at the G1-league etc.). I Hope im clear enough

Answer (score 5):

The free to watch tournaments in Dota2 currently are:

- [The International 1](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/The_International/2011)
- [The International 2](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/The_International/2012) and its [East](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/The_International/2012/East_Qualifiers) and [West](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/The_International/2012/West_Qualifiers) qualifiers.
- [The International 3](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/The_International/2013) and its [East](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/The_International/2013/East_Qualifiers) and [West](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/The_International/2013/West_Qualifiers) qualifiers.
- [The Nexon Starter League from GOM in Korea](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Nexon_Starter_League)
- [The Dreamhack Dota2 Invitational](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/DreamHack_2013/Invitational)

Answer (score 0):

Only the international The rest are free only on twitch TV on these channels:

http://www.twitch.tv/beyondthesummit/profile
beyond the summit

Join dota is split between :
http://www.twitch.tv/joindotared/profile
join dota red

http://www.twitch.tv/joindotablue/profile
join dota blue

Comment: Are past international tournaments available still? Anywhere I can easily find them in-game?

Comment: Yes but you have to purchase the tickets from the in-game store, or you can find the VODs (replays of the matches) on official websites or twitch channels that i mentioned there.

Comment: Also you can check upcoming tournament at www.joindota.com you can make an account, set up your location and the time for the tournaments will scale up to you timezone. And you can find there the replays as well, maybe a bit more centralized.

Comment: I really wonder why i got downvoted

Comment: I've just upvoted, but perhaps it's because I asked about in-game viewing, but you've concentrated on streaming services. If the international tournaments are free does this mean I can access all of them in game (previous years as well as this year) for example?

Comment: Yes only those this is what i stated first, then i added that eventually if you want to see any other tournaments ingame, you have to purchase tickets OR you can watch any tournament for free on joinDota/twitch.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Yes you can find the previous international tournaments. Just go to the watch tab, and keep pressing back until you get to TI2. It's not very user-friendly at the moment.

Comment: @Decency: Ahh, thanks. Tried the first match in that tournament and it said "Replay Unavailable", then i tried the finals and I can download them still so that's something!

Comment: last years dreamhack is also free to watch and available ingame.